# Linking openCV to clion project

Tags: c++, opencv, intellij-idea, clion

I am a newbie with clion and I want to compile my project.

If I compile it in the console: g++ -o a main.cpp -std=c++11 `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -lboost_system
... it works fine.

When I add it to Cmake/Cache --> CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, it will be parsed to 
"pkg-config opencv 
--cflags 
--libs" what is not wanted.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. From the command line**

You could set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:
**export CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=`pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`** (notice the back ticks)

**2. Inside the `CMakeLists.txt` file/your cmake file:**

If you are using OpenCV 2.4 or later, then you could do it using just:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui imgproc)
```

Other way would be:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui imgproc)
```

(Add/subtract other OpenCV modules too as required by your project)